# In a signal handler, how to know where the program is interrupted?

Tags: c++, c, linux, signals, interrupt

On x86 (either 64-bit or 32-bit) Linux --
for example:

```
void signal_handler(int) {
   // want to know where the program is interrupted ...
}

int main() {
    ...
    signal(SIGALRM, signal_handler);
    alarm(5);
    ...
    printf(...); <------- at this point, we trigger signal_handler
    ...
}
```

In signal_handler, how can we know we are interrupted at printf in main()?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [sigaction](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) with SA_SIGINFO set in sa_flags.

Prototype code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1  /* To pick up REG_RIP */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <assert.h>

static void
handler(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    const ucontext_t *con = (ucontext_t *)context;

    /* I know, never call printf from a signal handler.  Meh. */
    printf("IP: %lx\n", con->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP]);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigaction sa = { };
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    assert(sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL) == 0);
    for (;;);
    return 0;
}
```

Run it and hit <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>.  (Use <kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd> to terminate...)

This is for x86_64.  For 32-bit x86, use `REG_EIP` instead of `REG_RIP`.

[edit]

Of course, if you are actually in a library function (like `printf`) or a system call (like `write`), the RIP/EIP register might point somewhere funny...

You might want to use [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/) to crawl the stack.

Comment: printf is generally not reentrant, so if you happen to be in printf when you get the signal, this will probably print garbage or crash...

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, I know. This sample program works fine on its own (probably), and it was the easiest way to demonstrate the principle.  But that is why I included the comment and called it "prototype code" :-)

Comment: Any idea how to port this to ARM platform? Should I really use the instruction pointer? It will point to my handler code, I guess. I thought the link register may be a better choice?!

Comment: @Philippos: I suggest looking at the libunwind and/or libbacktrace libraries. Both exist for ARM, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your OS / Platform, it could be in a variety of areas:

- On the current stack a set number of registers deep
- On an/the interrupt stack
- Within some sort of callback associated with your signal routine...

Without having additional info, I don't think we can track this much further.  Adding a C/C++ tag to your might generate more responses and views.

Comment: Thanks. I try to use sigaction. It seems that ucontext_t may help a bit. But no any progress now ..

Answer (score 1):

> In signal_handler, how can we know we are interrupted at printf in main()?
>   You can't, at least not from a C, C++, or POSIX perspective. Your operating system may provide OS-specific calls that let you poke at the stack. That's more than a bit dubious, though.

With timer-based signals, which instruction triggered the signal is a toss of the coin.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround idea: if there are only a small number of places which can trigger a signal handler or you are only interested in which bigger block it happened you could maintain that in a variable.

```
entered = 1; // or entered = ENTER_PRINTF1;
printf(....);
```